# What would be the size of this enum, in bytes? C++

Tags: c++

What would be the size of this enum, in bytes? C++

```
enum Cars { Toyota, Suzuki, Volkswa, Mitsubish, Alfarome, Holden, Bradleys };
```

Comment: This is probably implementation detail. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Comment: I'd think 1, 2, 4, and 8 are plausible size.

Comment: Well I know it's not 8, as that was my initial answer. The other options are 7, 28 and 32. I think it's 32 then?

Comment: I guess it's something like sizeof(Cars), with an absolute error of 0. And of course is implementation and machine dependant.

Comment: Is this some homework ? You can use the sizeof macro ...

Comment: Not homework just a random questions. If it's a multiple choice question, the options are 7, 8, 28 or 32. I tried 8. It turned out wrong.

Comment: @CristianoAraujo: `sizeof` is an operator, not a macro.

Comment: @LorenzoBelli Are you perchance a member of the [tautology club](http://xkcd.com/703/)?

Comment: @Wulfinite That test is rubbish, then. This clearly depends on the size of `int`, which means it's compiler- and system-dependent. And I don't think any sane system has an `int` sized at 7, 28 or 32 *bytes.* So the only remotely reasonable answer is 8. If it were bits, 32 might be considered as well (the size of a typical `int` being 4 bytes on 8-bits-per-byte machines).

Comment: You said bytes but your possible answers seem to be in bits.

Comment: The answer is to be answered in bytes

Comment: The question _cannot_ be answered in bytes, in general. It's a broken question.

Comment: The answer is 28 bytes apparently..

Comment: @Wulfinite: Your friend is _wrong_. He or she is making up rubbish.

Comment: This enum represents the literal values of days as integers. Referring to the numeric types table, you see that an int takes 4 bytes of memory. 7 days x 4 bytes each would require 28 bytes of memory.

Comment: Oh, the ignorance this question is revealing!

Comment: @Wulfinite The size of `int` is implementation defined as well, there are only guarantees such as `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`.

Comment: The enum itself requires no storage. Any variable that will store values from this enum requires enough space to store *one* value from this enum. Nothing will require space to store *all* values from it.

Comment: 28 bytes: 4 bytes to store the enum value, 24 bytes for the Volkswagen cheat software.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think 3 and 5 are also plausible solutions. There are systems where [sizeof(int) == 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17834838/995714)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: *"The question cannot be answered in bytes, in general."* - Why not? Isn't bytes the unit of what `sizeof` returns?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: No, I mean, it cannot be answered _at all_ in general, because the result is unspecified by the C++ standard. _The question being answered in bytes_ is a subset of _the question being answered at all_, so that is also impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of an enum in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/366017/995714), [Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1113855/995714), [How can i know the size of the enum Days? Will it be equal to `7*4(sizeof(int)) = 28`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9972345/995714)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ah OK. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl but there isn't a specified size for types in C++

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: What about `CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl it's not defined either. The only guarantee is that `CHAR_BIT >= 8`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Well, yes and no. I'd say it's defined in the context of a particular implementation, but undefined in general.

Comment: Since there are 7 distinct values then you need `ceil(log2(7)) = 3` bits to represent all possible values. Any additional bits are just padding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From §7.2/5 of the C++ standard, you have that in your case the underlying type is not *fixed*:

> The underlying type can be explicitly specified using an enum-base. For a scoped enumeration type, the underlying type is int if it is not explicitly specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type is said to be fixed. [...]

Which leads to §7.2/7:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

---

Summing up, for your enumeration the underlying type is at most an `int` or `unsigned int`. You can check the size via `sizeof`, and the type via `typeid`. Example checking code that prettifies the result with g++ (not necessary with Visual C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>     // std::type_info
#include <type_traits>  // std::underlying_type
using namespace std;

int const bits_per_byte = CHAR_BIT;

#ifdef __GNUC__
#   include <cxxabi.h>      // abi::*, free
#   include <string>        // std::string

    auto display_name( type_info const& info )
        -> string
    {
        int   status;
        char* demangled = abi::__cxa_demangle( info.name(), 0, 0, &status );
        string result = demangled;
        free( demangled );
        return result;
    }
#else
    auto display_name( type_info const& info )
        -> string
    { return info.name(); }    
#endif // __GNUC__

enum Cars {
    Toyota, Suzuki, Volkswa, Mitsubish, Alfarome, Holden, Bradleys
    };

auto main() -> int
{
    using Cars_type = typename underlying_type< Cars >::type;
    type_info const& info = typeid( Cars_type );
    cout << "This compiler is " << bits_per_byte*sizeof(void*) << "-bit.\n";
    cout << "Underlying type is '" << display_name( info ) << "'.\n";
    cout << "Size = " << sizeof( Cars ) << " bytes.\n";
}
```

Output with MinGW g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0:

```
This compiler is 64-bit.
Underlying type is 'unsigned int'.
Size = 4 bytes.
```

Comment: Well it's not a question that I formed, just a random question a friend gave me, and I answered 8, which was wrong. The remaining options are 7, 28 and 32. Which would you think it would be?

Comment: @Wulfinite: None of the above.

Comment: @Wulfinite Tell your friend the question is not well posed

Comment: @Wulfinite: Utter nonsense.

Comment: Well ask your friend!

Comment: It's not.​​​​​​ Your friend is making up complete rubbish.

Comment: This enum represents the literal values of days as integers. Referring to the numeric types table, you see that an int takes 4 bytes of memory. 7 days x 4 bytes each would require 28 bytes of memory. This is the only possible way of looking at it.

Comment: @Wulfinite: That's also complete rubbish. Where are you getting this crap?

Comment: @Wulfinite: Could it be that the entire misunderstanding here is the misconception that type sizes are fixed by the C++ standard? Well, they are not. There are minimum sizes and some guarantees about certain types being at least as big as others, but that's all. This is completely unlike e.g. Java.

Comment: C, not C++, but very similar to your rubbish question. The guy also has a wrong premise about enum. [How can i know the size of the enum Days? Will it be equal to 7*4(sizeof(int)) = 28](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9972345/995714). How does it take 7*4 bytes when it can only store 1 value at a time, not all 7 values. It's not a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) type

Answer (score 7):

The size depends on the platform/implementation.

In C++11, you can specify the underlying type (and hence the size).
In the following example the size would be 1 byte:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

enum cars : std::uint8_t {
    Toyota, Suzuki, Volkswa, Mitsubish, Alfarome, Holden, Bradleys
};

int main() {
    cars my_car = cars::Toyota;
    std::cout << sizeof(my_car) << std::endl;
};
```

Returns:

```
1
```

While

```
enum cars : std::uint32_t { ...
```

Returns:

```
4
```

Comment: I think the OP should run this code, with and without specifying the underlying type. That should prove that none of the multiple choice answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Each enumeration is a separate entity.

The compiler needs to allocate enough storage to hold the highest value of the enumeration.

In your case, there are 7 entities.  The compiler needs to allocate enough storage to hold the value 7.

The minimum size of an addressable data type is 1.

If you create a variable of the `enum` type, it must have a **minimum** size of 1.  However, the compiler can choose a size that is more optimal for the architecture (platform), such as 2 bytes (16-bit word), 4 bytes (32-bit word) or other.

If the enumeration items are used individually, like in an `if` statement, the compiler may not allocate any data storage and emit the values into an instruction in the executable.

So the answer to your question is:  the minimum space for a variable of the enum type is 1.  What your compiler uses is dependent on the compiler and the platform.  If the enumeration value is used in an expression, the compiler may choose to put the value in the instruction, so there will be zero data space allocated.